# If $U$ is separable and $V \subset U$, then $V$ is separable

Tags: functional-analysis

Assume that $X$ is a normed linear vector space. 
I am trying to prove that If $U$ is separable and $V \subset U$, then $V$ is separable.

This is the proof.

Suppose $W=\{W_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a countable set and is dense.

Introduce a set $Y=(m,n) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$  for which their is a vector $v \in V$ such that $$||v - w_n|| \leq \frac{1}{m}$$

For every pair $(m,n) \in Y$ we choose a vector $v_{mn}  \in V$ satisfying $$||v_{mn} -w_n|| \leq \frac{1}{m}$$

Then the set $$W_1 =\{V_{mn} : (m,n) \in Y \}$$ is countable.

> How does this show that  $W_1 =\{v_{mn} : (m,n) \in Y \}$ is countable?

Now we show $W_1$ is a dense subset of $V$ so for every $j \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists an $n(j)$ such that $$||v-w_{n(j}|| \leq \frac{1}{j}$$

So $(j, n(j)) \in Y$
and $$||v-v_{j,n(j)}|| \leq ||v-w_{n(j)}||+||w_{n(j)}-v_{j,n(j)}|| \leq \frac{2}{j}$$

hence $$v_{j,n(j)} \to v $$ as $j \to \infty$

> How does this show that $W_1$ is a dense subset of $V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$W_1$ is countable because $Y$ is countable (which is countable because it is a subset of the countable set $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$).

To show that $W_1$ is dense in $V$ we might show that its intersects every non-empty subset of $V$. But the sequence criterion used here works as well: We show that for every point $v\in V$, there is a sequence of points in $W_1$ that converges to $v$.

*Remark:* Note that the whole proof does not really make use of *normed linear space*. The very same argument works for *metric space*.

Comment: So is $\frac{2}{j} \in V$? Also in my proof, what is $f$?

Comment: Also how can we swap $v_{j,n(j)}$ and $w_{n(j)}$?

Comment: $f$ should actually be $v$. We have $\|v-w_{n(j)}\|\le \frac1j$ by choice of $n(j)$, then $\|v_{j,n(j)}-w_{n(j)}\|\le\frac1j$ because $(j,n(j))\in Y$ and then $\|v-v_{j,n(j)}\|\le\frac2j$ from the triangle inequality.